# Can I use Laravel 5 Middleware to allow packages to override app routes?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-5, laravel-middleware

I would like to be able to override the routes defined in app/Http/routes.php with a route in a package.

For example, in app/Http/routes.php I might have this:

```
Route::get('/search/{type?}',['as' => 'search','uses' => 'SearchController@search']);
```

I want to be able to define this in /vendor/author/package/src/Http/routes.php:

```
Route::get('/search/properties', ['as' => 'properties','uses' => 'PropertyController@search']);
```

The app/Http/routes.php file is loaded first so the route in their is used, not the package.

In Laravel 4 I would do this using App::before or App::after, giving them a priority.

Like so in the package routes:

```
App::before(function() {
    Route::get('/search/properties', ['as' => 'properties','uses' => 'PropertyController@search']);
});
```

I don't know how to achieve this in Laravel 5. I found this https://mattstauffer.co/blog/laravel-5.0-middleware-filter-style, but don't know how to use that to do what I want.

Edit: The Laravel 4 way of doing this would allow this priority to be set per route, so I'm not just loading all of the package routes before the app.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to change the order in which routes are registered by changing the order of service providers in `config/app.php`.

Currently it probably looks somewhat like this:

```
'providers' => [
    // ...
    'App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider',
    // ...
    'Vendor\Package\PackageServiceProvider',
],
```

Now just change the order so the package is loaded first:

```
'providers' => [
    // ...
    'Vendor\Package\PackageServiceProvider',  // register package routes first
    'App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider',
    // ...
],
```

---

To just prioritize specific routes you can (ab)use the service providers `register()` method. I don't really like method but it works and I couldn't find anything better...

When the service providers are loaded the `register()` method of every provider is called. After that (and in the same order) the `boot()` method. That means independent of the order of your providers the `register()` method in your package will always be called before the `boot()` method in the `RouteServiceProvider`. This could look somewhat like this:

```
class PackageServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {
    public function boot(){
        // register the regular package routes
    }

    public function register(){
        // register route "overrides"
        // for example like this: (obviously you could also load a file)
        app('router')->get('/search/properties', ['as' => 'properties','uses' => 'PropertyController@search']);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, the only issue with this is that it would apply to all routes in the package, so I wouldn't be able to define different priorities for each one.

Comment: Yes that's correct. I don't know if that's even possible since the routes are loaded in the boot method of the `RouteServiceProvider`. I'll let you know if I find something out...